# Write data to csv in the right place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv
import datetime
from time import strftime
now = [strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]
t = datetime.datetime.now()
a=[100,101,102,103,104]
b=[86,87,88,89,90]
c=[95,96,97,98,99]
d=[71,72,73,74,75]
with open('ddd.csv', 'a',newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(now)
    writer.writerow(a)
    writer.writerow(b)
    writer.writerow(c)
    writer.writerow(d)
```

In the case,it will output picture 1. I don't want picture 1.

[image: screenshot 1]

I need to write the number in picture 2.

[image: screenshot 2]

How can I write the data to the location I want?

I don't want to use `[" ","71","72","73","74","75"]` to make it . I think I will face another problem in this way if data is more than before.

Comment: Could it be that you need an actual Excel writer, like [`xlsxwriter`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)?

Comment: You WANT cell A2 to be empty, but you DON'T want to use an empty string in the list? Why not?

Comment: I could not reproduce the empty-line error. Please post the actual CSV files, not their Excel representations. Also `[100,101,102,103,104]` must be `[strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),100,101,102,103,104]` and all other rows must start with an empty cell, e.g. `[,86,87,88,89,90]`.

Comment: I can reproduce the "error".  It has to do with how Microsoft Excel interprets the CSV file.  The question is, does the OP want a CSV file, or an Excel file?

Comment: CSV files. DYZ you means notepad?
I do not know much about the csv.
i have to read more information about csv.

Comment: The [CSV file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is basically a 2D matrix or table of rows and columns, so you must add a blank item to the front of rows which lack a timestamp value in order to properly make one. This is an easy "problem" to handle when the file is later read and processed.

Comment: @martineau: Yes, but CSV is not intended to be a display format, which is what kovac wants.

Comment: @kovac: Do you really need a CSV file?

Comment: @mike: You must be able to read minds—or between the lines, because the subject of the question make it appear to be about writing data to a csv file...

Comment: @martineau: What is apparent is that he is a beginner.  He may be using CSV because he thinks that he has to.  The question appears to be about display formatting, which is what Excel files are about, not CSV files.

Comment: @Mike yes, i am beginner . I try to do data analysis.Data from internet.
I want to make data neatly.
After read yours comments, i found there are  somethings  that i don't know.I have learned that i should read more about csv.
If there are any suggestion,tell me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a column of mostly blanks, generate the rows that way:

```
import csv
import time

now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
rows = [[now,100,101,102,103,104],
        ['',86,87,88,89,90],
        ['',95,96,97,98,99],
        ['',71,72,73,74,75]]
with open('ddd.csv','w',newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('ddd.csv', 'a',newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([now] + a)
    writer.writerow([None] + b)
    writer.writerow([None] + c)
    writer.writerow([None] + d)
```

Like this?

Comment: What he seems to want is a hack of CSV, which isn't what CSV is for.